# Python Garbage-Collector and Class Variables

Tags: python, class, variables, garbage

I have small question about garbage collection in Python.

Let's assume that i have class G

```
class G:
    someclassvariable = something
    def somemethod():
        nothing important here
```

I create instance of Class G that will be later collected by GC and modify someclassvariable.
Is is safe to assume that the value of someclassvariable will remain modified?
(In another words i am asking is GC doing anything with Class variables and if yes then what is he doing with them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: yes ;

the class variable remains modified, even when all instances are being unreferenced and garbage collected.

resources:

- [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)
- http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch22s06.html
- http://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/

and you may find a lot of other documentation on the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was testing it and it looked that way but wanted to be sure.